# Check is pre-commit existed: npm

Tags: npm, pre-commit-hook, husky

I have a script in `package.json`:

```json
"prepare": "husky install && npx husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npx lint-staged\""
```

But each time I run `npm i`, new `npx lint-staged` create in `pre-commit` file.

If I run 3 times:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
npx lint-staged
npx lint-staged
```

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Why _do_ you have `husky add` in your prepare script?!

Comment: Because i ignore `.husky`, Should I do that?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Husky already sets up the `.husky` directory with an appropriate `.gitignore`.